# jQuery UI Dialog with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to write a functionality where if we pass the scope and template, it should show the given template in a jQuery UI dialog with the all working bindings from the given scope.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainDiv" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="button" value="show dialog" ng-click="showTemplateDialog()" />
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dialogTemplate">
    <div>
        This is template div.
        <span>Message: </span>
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.showTemplateDialog = function() {
        alert("hi")
        var newScope = $scope.$new();
        newScope.message = "This is some message";
        $scope.showDialog(newScope, "dialogTemplate")
    };
    $scope.showDialog = function(dialogScope, template) {
        var div = $("<div style='' id='dialog' title='Test Dialog' ng-include=\"'" + template + "'\"></div>");
        $compile(div)(dialogScope);
        $("#mainDiv").append(div);
        div.dialog();
    }
})
```

The problem is when I call `div.dialog()`, it throws following error in `jquery-ui.min.js`

```
Unhandled exception at line 9, column 26027 in http://localhost/TestApp/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'display' of undefined or null reference
```

Please suggest some way to resolve this error. Or suggest some other way to show and html/template in jQuery dialog using angularjs.

Comment: BTW, you have a HTML syntax error at the input element.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried what Hubert suggested, but still it was not working. Then I realize when I am creating the div, it's not properly getting created and was showing `localName` of the html element as null.

Then I did some changes in my code and it worked. I just added another div inside the div I was creating and put ng-include on that.

Here is the updated code:

```
$scope.showDialog = function(dialogScope, template) {
        var div = $("<div id='dialog' title='Test Dialog' ><div ng-include=\"'" + template + "'\"></div></div>");    
        $compile(div)(dialogScope);
        $("#mainDiv").append(div);
        div.dialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of `div` would be a JQuery object. I would try passing the HTML string directly to `compile()`. The result of compile(html)(scope) is an array IIRC, so you probably want to append its first element `[0]`.

EDIT: I just tried that and it seems Angular won't allow `ng-include` being compiled this way.